# asp:label clear text using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var errMessage = '';
function ShowError() {
    var options = {};
    if (arguments.length == 1)
        options = arguments[0];

    var title = '<%= AlertTitle.Text.Replace("'", "\'") %>';
  errMessage = $('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').html().replace(/\\'/g, "'");
        $('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').html('');
    }

    $("#errDlgText").html(errMessage);

    if (options.title != undefined)
        title = options.title;

    var focusOn = null;
    if (options.setFocus != undefined)
        focusOn = options.setFocus;

    var onOK = null;
    if (options.onOK != undefined)
        onOK = options.onOK;

    if (errMessage == '')
        return;

    $("#errDialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                if (onOK != null)
                    onOK();

            errMessage = '';
            $('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').html('');
            $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        title: title,
        close: function () {
            errMessage = '';
            $('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').html('');
            if (focusOn != null)
                focusOn.focus();
        }
    });
}
//-->
</script>
```

When a message is displayed I want to clear the label.
I do that using this line:

```
$('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').html('');
```

however, my AlertLiteral, still contains the original text.
It is never emptied.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your client side debugger can tell you a lot

Comment: use `$('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>').text('');` instead.

Comment: when you do "$('#<%= AlertLiteral.ClientID %>')" the element is returned correctly, what kind of object is ? a div ?

Comment: it is a label contained in a div :
<div style="display: none">
        <asp:Literal ID="AlertTitle" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="AlertLiteral" runat="server" />
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it, thanks to the tips of Amit and suprabhat.
I'm using the .text now, instead of .html

And there was another problem which prevented the message from being emptied.